# I’m looking for a word that means fold over

Tags: single-word-requests

This word is on the tip of my tongue but it starts with a c and means that it was surrendered or they folder over...

Here’s the sentence
“It was c____, and they gave up.”

Comment: Crumple?.......

Comment: Ceded? Conceded? "Fold over" isn't right.  I'm just guessing at words that would fill in your blank.

Comment: can we have a full meaningful phrase, what did they give up was it a battle, a game of chess, the hunt for buffalo as this al may affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

They "**capitulated**" meaning they gave up or surrendered in the effort.

> It (the battle) was **capitulated**, and they gave up.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/capitulate